# extract some texts from html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have html "page" as follows:

```
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp;</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt'>ヤブツバキクラス（常緑広葉樹林）</span><span
style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'> <span
lang=EN-US>Camellietea japonicae</span><span lang=EN-US> Miyawaki <i>et</i>
Ohba 1963<br>
</span></span><span style='font-size:11.0pt'>　リュウキュウガキ－クスノハガシワオーダー</span><span
style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'> <span
lang=EN-US>Diospyro maritimae-Mallotetalia philippensis</span><span lang=EN-US>
Fujiwara 1981<br>
</span></span><span style='font-size:11.0pt'>　　ナガミボチョウジ－リュウキュウガキ群団</span><span
style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'> <span
lang=EN-US>Psychotrio manilensis-Diospyrion maritimae</span><span lang=EN-US>
Niiro <i>et al.</i> 1974<br>
```

I need to extract as follows:

ヤブツバキクラス（常緑広葉樹林), Camellietea japonicae

リュウキュウガキ－クスノハガシワオーダー, Diospyro maritimae-Mallotetalia philippensis

ナガミボチョウジ－リュウキュウガキ群団, Psychotrio manilensis-Diospyrion maritimae

I tried as:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features="lxml")

rows = soup.find_all('span')
for row in rows:
        print (row.text.strip().split(' ')[0])
```

But, it extracted as follows:

```
ヤブツバキクラス（常緑広葉樹林）
Camellietea
Camellietea
Miyawaki
リュウキュウガキ−クスノハガシワオーダー
Diospyro
Diospyro
Fujiwara
ナガミボチョウジ−リュウキュウガキ群団
Psychotrio
Psychotrio
Niiro
```

Comment: The text blocks like "Miyawaki" are also inside span tags and hence are being picked up. Is there a specific pattern that you want to pick up apart from just being inside the `<span>` tag?

Comment: 1. I need to extract the text between `<span
lang=EN-US>......</span><span`; i.e., Camellietea japonicae

Comment: 2. I need to extract text between `<span style='font-size:11.0pt'>..........</span><span
style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>`, i.e., ヤブツバキクラス（常緑広葉樹林）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use :first-child and attribute=value selectors with bs4 4.7.1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:11.0pt'>ヤブツバキクラス（常緑広葉樹林）</span><span
style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'> <span
lang=EN-US>Camellietea japonicae</span><span lang=EN-US> Miyawaki <i>et</i>
Ohba 1963<br>
</span></span><span style='font-size:11.0pt'>　リュウキュウガキ－クスノハガシワオーダー</span><span
style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'> <span
lang=EN-US>Diospyro maritimae-Mallotetalia philippensis</span><span lang=EN-US>
Fujiwara 1981<br>
</span></span><span style='font-size:11.0pt'>　　ナガミボチョウジ－リュウキュウガキ群団</span><span
style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'> <span
lang=EN-US>Psychotrio manilensis-Diospyrion maritimae</span><span lang=EN-US>
Niiro <i>et al.</i> 1974<br>
  '''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print([i.text.strip() for i in item.select('span[style="font-size:11.0pt"], [lang=EN-US]:first-child')])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Step through the results and take the first two of every four spans:

```
for i in range(1, len(rows), 4):
    print(rows[i].string.strip(), 
          list(rows[i+1].children)[1].string.strip())

#ヤブツバキクラス（常緑広葉樹林）Camellietea japonicae
#リュウキュウガキ－クスノハガシワオーダー Diospyro maritimae-Mallotetalia philippensis
#ナガミボチョウジ－リュウキュウガキ群団 Psychotrio manilensis-Diospyrion maritimae
```